# Looking for PyQt5 chart with ranged (absolute Y-axis) Stacked Bar

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtcharts

I am looking for a bar chart where smaller bars in the same series are NOT overlapped with larger ones( not visa versa), so all bars in all series are visible, and their height corresponds to their real value on Y-axis.

But, unfortunately, I could only find a bar chart (QStackedBarSeries) where the column height is equal to the accumulated value of the included bars.,

not like on the pic below:

[image: QStackedBarSeries with accumulated height]

Answer (score 0):

I've also recently faced this issue. I don't think there is a direct way of doing it, but I came up with this workaround.

For the interested part you could write something like this:

```
self.partials = np.array([1000, 300, 100, 800])
self.totals = np.array([1500, 400, 150, 900])

partialSet = QBarSet("Subset")
partialSet.setColor(QColor(169, 172, 241))
totalsSet = QBarSet("Total")
totalsSet.setColor(QColor(117, 120, 237))
partialSet.append(self.partials)
totalsSet.append(np.subtract(self.totals, self.partials))

series = QStackedBarSeries()
series.append(partialSet)
series.append(totalsSet)
```

Where the result is something like this:
[image: example image]

The idea is to do the subtraction of the series yourself in order to let appear the right values. If you have more than two bars stacked you could adjust according to your needs.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not a solution because smallest bar in series have to overlap bigger bar at the bottom, in turn, the most largest bars in series have to be in background position, so do not overlap other  bars in the same series, it's like on family's photo :)) .. that's the meaning of this type of charts, you always see ranged colour bars, where the height of series equal to height of max bar.